# Sending a generic list parameter to a JAX-RS web service

Tags: java, jax-rs

How can I send a generic list parameter to a JAX-RS service?

Here is the method signature:

```java
@POST
@Path("findcustomers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void FindCustomers(@PathParam("branchId") long branchId, 
                          @PathParam("searchOptions") List<SearchOption> searchOptions) 
                          throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

`SearchOption` is a simple Java class composed of primitive types:

```java
class SearchOption {
    int channelId;
    int locationId;
    int targetStatus;
}
```

The code above raises an exception stating something like:

> No injection source found for a parameter of type [put method signature here]

Comment: Why don't you send it in the request payload or send your search criteria as query parameters?

Comment: By the way, ensure you are using [`javax.ws.rs.PathParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) instead of [`javax.websocket.server.PathParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/PathParam.html).

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Thanks. There are multiple options to send to server and all of them are complex objects. Is it possible to send all of them as query parameters?

Comment: What kind of complex objects?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Edited my question, it is composed of primitive types.

Comment: Once you are already using `POST`, I would send it in the request payload as JSON, for example.

Comment: Another option would be send a JSON as a query parameter.

Comment: I could write an answer explaining how to do that, if you want to.

Comment: Your `SearchOption` class needs to follow the rules of what is allowed as  `@PathParam` type. Look at the bullet points in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html). Basically once you use one of those rules you will need to construct the type yourself from a string. JAX-RS has no idea how to create you `SearchOptions` from a string. But it give you options on how you can tell it how to create it, by following one of those rules

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin That would be great. I'm a C# developer and having a hard time applying the concepts of Web API development to Jax-rs :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a long and painful research, I've found the solution.

In order to be able to accept a POJO in a service method, you need to add @XmlRootElement attribute to your POJO, write a no-argument constructor in the class and have getters/setters for the fields.

I've been using Maven so here's the minimum required dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can now send and receive POJO objects in your api methods.